# 'End' key not going beyond trailing whitespace of line in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, end-of-line, settings

When I press the `End` key (in Windows) to get to the end of the line in Eclipse, I don't get to the actual end of the line if there's trailing whitespace. Instead I get to the beginning of the trailing whitespace, and subsequently pressing `End` causes the cursor to alternate between the end and beginning of the whitespace. Is there a way to make it always go to the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off »Smart caret positioning at line start and end« in `Preferences → General → Editors → Text Editors`. Unfortunately, this seems to be only switchable for both the `Home` and `End` keys at the same time. So you'll have to decide whether you want a working `End` key or a smart `Home` key.

Personally, I need the `Home` key more, so I leave it as it is. I can't think of any example of a scenario where the `End` behavior of Eclipse could be of any use. The ways of the Eclipse devs seem to be beyond human understanding.

(Used Eclipse version: Mars.2/4.5.2)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `Home` key. I needed it to get to the beginning of a line!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Keys and look at the settings for "Line End" and "Text End". Make sure you have the End key set only for Line End.

Comment: Didn't work. "Text End" seems to go to the end of the document, not the end of the line, and was bound to ctrl+End. The only thing that is bound to End without modifiers is "Line End".

Comment: Eclipse comes in many forms; @Blrp, what implementation/version are you using? I tried this answer for Android Studio, which is basically Eclipse, but that doesn't have this option. I did find a related option at File/Settings/IDE Settings/Editor/Smart Keys, which includes a Home checkbox I found works to disable this behaviour at the other end of the line.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers / Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) / Build id: 20150219-0600